# Is USB keyboard faster than PS/2?

Tags: usb, keyboard, ps2

I recently joined a CNC manufacturing company and they have given me a project to work on. So the issue is the MDI keypad used in their CNC machine is of PS/2 interface and they feel that it is slower, and sometimes the system hangs because of this. Hence they want to change the keyboard interface to USB.

After doing a bit of research it appears to be that PS/2 keyboards are actually faster than USB keyboard (Or at least there shouldn't be any noticeable difference between the two). And also that USB interface quite complex and costlier too.

So my question is which keypad interface do usual CNC machines have and do USB interface make a difference in data rate compared to PS/2?

Comment: There's no relevant difference in speed between PS/2 and USB keyboards.  If the problem is that their controller is slow to respond to each keypress, then changing to USB is not going to make any difference.

Comment: The OS is what will make the difference, although it really should not matter.

Comment: Pro gamers prefer PS/2 because USB keyboards can have a longer latency between keypress and reaction. But that's talking about milliseconds and not hanging the whole system. Sounds like a bad PS/2 driver or OS or keypad controller or user interface. Nothing wrong with either USB or PS/2 inherently.

Comment: I've heard that Windows 10 lacks support for PS/2 keyboards, but I find that hard to believe.

Comment: Ok, so the OS used in the machine is On-time RTOS 32 and a Single board Computer (SBC) is used as a host. Maybe the problem is with OS I guess.

Comment: In this case the keyboard may *not* be PS/2 at all, they might just use the connector for a totally different keyboard protocol. You should verify that this is really PS/2, e.g. in the documentation.

Comment: @Turbo J What do you mean by a totally different keyboard protocol? Could you please elaborate on that. I know that there is a PS/2 connector used and a AT89C51 microcontroller is used

Comment: I bet, PC gamers would know the answer to this.  They are usually aware about various lags and latencies.

Answer (score 0):

Depending how your machine software/OS reacts to keyboard interrupts it might explain the delay. PS2 is more likely to use hardware interrupt than USB and depending of interrupt programming it might cause hanging issues. (Let's say a key is stuck, it will interrupt the main program non-stop)

USB keyboard might patch the problem...